# Printing the jar version using in the spring boot application in logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

Is it possible to print the version of the jar we are using the pom.xml in logs.

For example, I'm using the Jar **aspose-email** in the application, I want to print the version whichever I'm using in logs.

If possible, how to do it

Comment: Why? You have build a particular state which is recorded in your git repo you have released you app and hopefully made a tag to your release state.. thats it?

Answer (score 1):

To only "print it (any "maven properties") to log":

---

1. pom.xml:

   ```
   <properties>
     <foo>bar</foo>
     ...
   ```

   (this can be used throughout the pom...)
2. application.properties:

   ```properties
   my.domain.someKey=@foo@
   ```
3. Some bean referencing it as `@Value("${my.domain.someKey})String foo`.
4. ...and logging it. (`LOGGER.info(foo)`)

Refs:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

  > ***Note***: Since the application.properties and application.yml files accept Spring style placeholders (`${…​}`), the Maven filtering is changed to use `@..@` placeholders. (You can override that by setting a **Maven** property called `resource.delimiter`.)

---

A "production ready" [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) (web exposure) approach:

---

Assuming this  [spring-boot-starter](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,actuator)(web,actuator).

We add this to our `application.properties`:

```properties
# we need this (jmx is exposed by default):
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info
# ... and this (enables info.* properties):
management.info.env.enabled=true
# ...then can write here arbitrary values, starting with info.*
info.foo=foo
# ...or "filtered" from the pom, like e.g:
info.app.spring-boot.version=@project.parent.version@
# we can use here also any pom.properties like @my.property@
# for pessimistic enablement/opt out:
#management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false 
#management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
```

And find them at `http://localhost:8080/actuator/info` , like:

```json
{"foo":"foo","app":{"spring-boot":{"version":"2.6.2"}}}
```

Refs:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.info (mainly)

Comment: Great solution, thank you. Works both for actuator and the logs. I used a @PostConstruct method on the Main class to output the app version to stdout.